# Why argo gives empty creationTimestamp?

Tags: argo-workflows

I need to create a timestamp at the beginning of my argo-WF and use this timestamp as input for several templates. I do this via a parameter "stage". Why is this parameter empty in below WF? I get the output

```
1234
abc
5678
```

but would expect

```
1234
abc25-11-20223 12.22.38
5678
```

WF-Code:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: cdr-extraction-
spec:
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: stage
        value: {{workflow.creationTimestamp.<%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S>}}
  entrypoint: main
  parallelism: 2500
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
       - - name: get-messy-output
           template: get-messy-output-template
       - - name: get-messy-output2
           template: get-messy-output-template

    - name: get-messy-output-template
      script:
        image: alpine
        command:
          - sh
        source: |
          echo 1234
          echo abc{{workflow.parameters.stage}}
          echo 5678
          sleep 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to include double-quotes: value: "{{workflow.creationTimestamp}}"